MongoDB and Compass won't TLS with Custom CA certs made with OpenSSL
This is a connected to previous question I asked:
Compass and MongoDB VPS instance won't establish TLS connection
where Wernfried Domscheit provided the solution, which raised further question.
Just like Wernfried Domscheit pointed out, if you know URL of MongoDB instance and you happen to know that LetsEncrypt certs are used for TLS, then nothing is stopping you from generating your own LetsEncrypt certs for this URL and connecting to MongoDB. The established fact is MongoDB only verifying the CA and validity of the cert and isn't verifying the contents of the cert provided by the client.
The non-obvious solution found that made Compass talk to MongoDB instance on VPS was to use LetsEncrypt certs generated by Certbot. The 2 files are used:

certKey.pem, which has host certificate and privkey;
intermRoot.pem, which has chain.pem and rootCA certitifates, wherein the RooCA is downloaded from LetsEncrypt website.

Those are attached to mongodb.conf end. Compass is happy to use certKey only. Connection establishes just fine. Apparently, not happy days, because it's fake TLS security - like explained above.
The truly secure solution would be make own, custom CA, which nobody can dodge, that MongoDB is actually verifying.
With OpenSSL I generated the custom CA, the host cert and the intermediate cert and they do pass verification against rootCA. But MongoDB isn't happy:
{"t":{"$date":"2024-12-07T22:13:18.040+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23256,   "ctx":"conn56","msg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed","attr":{"error":"SSL peer certificate validation failed: unsuitable certificate purpose"}}

Any ideas on how to fix this are appreciated.
Edit:
RootCA cert:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Intermediate cert:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

Host cert:
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----


Please provide your certificate files (without the private keys!)

In general it looks like you are not aware of the difference between client and server certificates. Not clear what you are looking about.

Edited. Please see the certs

"RootCA cert" and "Intermediate cert" are obviously the same.

I assume the wrong intermediate certificate is just a mistake from your side.
So, focus on your error. unsuitable certificate purpose indicates that you have wrong certificate purpose:
> openssl x509 -in giftbutton.com.crt -noout -ext extendedKeyUsage,keyUsage,nsComment
Netscape Comment:
    My First Certificate
X509v3 Key Usage:
    Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment
X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
    TLS Web Server Authentication

I guess, you try to use this certificate at Compass. This is a server certificate, however at Compass you need to create a client certificate, i.e. you need to set TLS Web Client Authentication.
Why did you set Non Repudiation? This property and the Netscape extensions are not needed.
Regarding intermediate certificates: On public web servers you have usually a Root-CA and an Intermediate-CA. In general there is no technical reason for it, it is more driven by organization challenges. Imagine the Let's Encrypt Root-CA would be compromised - there are billions of devices and browsers who trust in this Root-CA. It would be really a huge effort to remove and update this Root-CA on billions of devices. That's the reason for Intermediate-CA. If an Intermediate-CA gets compromised (maybe by an vindictive and angry service desk employee) then it is rather simple to revoke this Intermediate-CA in the Root-CA CRL.
Most likely in Let's Encrypt, only the CEO and CTO may have access to the private key of their Root-CA's in order to keep them protected.
In your small or private environment there is no technical reason to create any Intermediate-CA. In case your Root-CA gets compromised then you can simply replace the CA and the end-entity certificates.

Thanks for the explanation. MongoDB is so poorly documented and their products so no talking to each other, it takes weeks to work it all out. MongoDB never explain what they want - Server, Client or whatever! They just want A CERTIFICATE. I don't deal with certificates every day. I just want to enable TLS protection. I a startup. Not MongoDB senior expert. I hate documentation written by those who understands everything to those who understands everything. Cryptic language is used. It's lake using latin language in a church. There is no mentioning TLS Web Client Authentication in MongoDB docs

I do hate MongoDB now, but it's too late to switch. I hate it for the fact that without you I would never EVER worked it all out. Their docs are IN LATIN. Even THE SIMPLIEST thing - how to connect BY their product TO their product over TLS - isn't explained. They just don't care. Like those latin-preaching priests. Why would they? They have corporate clients to serve.

Please provide a link where MongoDB explains that this TLS Web Client Authentication actually exists. Please provide the link where do they explain to unfamiliar users who they design their documentation for the difference between each with examples.

Seriously. It this some undocumented feature of MongoDB? I have been reading their TLS docs thoroughly.

How would a server check whatever a client is providing? Surely the server needs to have a file identical to what's being provided? So surely, if there is differentiation now between "client certificate" and "server certificate" - both needs to be generated as a pack somehow to be aware of one another. Which leads to conclusion they are the same thing!

Did you check the links in this answer? I have to defend MongoDB, in the meantime the documentation regarding certificates improved a lot, it was much worse in earlier releases. However, you need to have a basic understanding about certificates.

Do you know why there is a huge amount of video bloggers that are getting INCOME from explaining things in plain English? Because of how original documentation sucks! Here an EXCELLENT playlist about certificates that I will try to implement and do another attempt of marrying 2 products of the same manufacturer together. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tGja8zN7E_0&ab_channel=TECHLAB

Ok, I have generated proper certificate chain according to this great TECHLAB playlist. All 3 certs are different and host cert passes validation agains root cert as well as interm cert passes validation agains root cert too. But it did not fix the problem "unsuitable cert purpose". My question is why LetsEncrypt certs don't cause this error?

As written, you miss the TLS Web Client Authentication extension. Most of the YouTube videos use TLS Web Server Authentication, because that is needed on web-servers and the most commonly used certificate type. The client (i.e. compass) needs a different certificate than the server. It is fully OK to use the same CA.

The host cert has them both. I made a screenshot of details of host cert being generated and it can be seen under Certificate Details / X509v3 Extended Key Usage: TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication.

The author of the playlist uses the conf files ca.txt. and mid-ca.txt from his website  https://argloop.com/tips/cloud/aws/openssl-how-to-create-chain-certificates/#ca    Do they need to be altered to make it work?

continues in another question opened https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79279812/compass-wont-connect-to-mongodb-over-tls-using-openssl-certificates/79281226#79281226
